# What is python equivalent of C#'s system.datetime.Ticks()?

Tags: python, c#, datetime, timedelta

I would like to get python equivalent of timestamp.Ticks(), however I need it to come from a python datetime, not a time object.

This is not the equivalent of [Get timer ticks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156330), which asks 'how do I get the number of ticks since midnight?'.

I am asking how do I get the number of ticks of a given datetime. By ticks I mean system.datetime.ticks:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

By 'get equivalent of' I mean 'what is the python code that will give the equivalent output of the C# code?'.

Comment: What is `timestamp.Ticks()`?

Comment: Why do you think there _should be_ exact equivalent? Programming languages are different styles with different purposes. They don't _have to_ includes equivalent methods, functions, data structures etc..

Comment: Sorry, I meant what is the python code that will give the equivalent value of the C# code

Comment: The question is very well-defined and clear - should not have been closed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the referenced page, [`DateTime.Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the number of ticks since `0001:01:01 00:00:00`. There are 10 million ticks per second.

In Python, `datetime(1, 1, 1)` represents `0001-01-01 00:00:00`. You can calculate the number of seconds using the `total_seconds()` method of a `timedelta`. Then, given a `datetime` object, the delta is calculated and converted to ticks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

t0 = datetime(1, 1, 1)
now = datetime.utcnow()
seconds = (now - t0).total_seconds()
ticks = seconds * 10**7
```

As a function this is:

```
def ticks(dt):
    return (dt - datetime(1, 1, 1)).total_seconds() * 10000000

>>> t = ticks(datetime.utcnow())
>>> t
6.356340009927151e+17
>>> long(t)
635634000992715136L
```

This value compares favourably to that returned by C# using `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`.

Notes:

- UTC times are assumed.
- The resolution of the `datetime` object is given by
  `datetime.resolution`, which is `datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 1)` or
  microsecond resolution (1e-06 seconds). C# Ticks are purported to be 1e-07 seconds.