# Porting DateTime Ticks from C# to Python

Tags: python, c#, datetime

I have a a **C#** line of code

```
string.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks)
```

That I am trying to port over to **Python**.
I'm having trouble understanding how to port two aspects:

I can't find an equivalent Python representation of `DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks` and `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`. I can get to a unix timestamp, but to my understanding, that is differnet than the **C#** `Ticks` object.

**Does anyone have any pointers to porting the above C# code to Python?**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: According to MSDN, `DateTime.MaxValue` is _equivalent to 23:59:59.9999999 UTC, December 31, 9999 in the Gregorian calendar, exactly one 100-nanosecond tick before 00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 10000._ What is the point of this code? Why is it trying to find how long it is until that date?

Comment: Take a look here: [DateTime.Ticks Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-6.0#remarks): `A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond (see TicksPerMillisecond) and 10 million ticks in a second.`

Answer (score 0):

I have data in Azure Table Storage that follows the [Log-Tail pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-patterns#log-tail-pattern) (which is identical to your code) and was looking for a way to filter on RowKey for better query performance than filtering on Timestamp and found that this worked for me:

```
from datetime import datetime

def row_key(dt):
    t = (datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999) - dt).total_seconds() * 10000000
    return f'{t:.0f}'
```

Adapted from
[What is python equivalent of C#'s system.datetime.Ticks()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366914/what-is-python-equivalent-of-cs-system-datetime-ticks)
and comment from @Johnny Mopp above